# 8085; Why RET doesn't require a 6 T-states Fetch cycle?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, assembly, 8085

The `CALL` instruction, requires 5 machine cycles, namely, `OPCODE-FETCH, MEMORY READ, MEMORY READ, MEMORY WRITE, MEMORY WRITE`. The OPCODE-FETCH cycle of CALL has 6 T-states [to take care of the decrements of  the Stack Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773146/9622343).

`RET` instruction [requires, 3 machine cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127748/number-of-machine-cycles-required-for-ret-instruction-in-8085), `OPCODE-FETCH, MEMORY READ, MEMORY READ`, even here, the microprocessor's got to **increment** the stack pointer **twice, as before**, to pop. But, the OPCODE-FETCH cycle only has 4 T-states, Why is that?

I've got a vague idea, as to why; in `CALL` and `PUSH` the SP has to be decremented first, unlike `RET` or `POP`. This first decrement alone is taken care in the last two T-states of `FETCH` cycle. But why would that require two T-states. Again, I'm really not sure about this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be insightful to analyse `CALL` instruction once more before talking about `RET` instruction.

**CALL INSTRUCTION IN 8085**

As you stated, it consists of: `Opcode Fetch`, `Memory Read`, `Memory Read`, `Memory Write`, `Memory Write`

8085 follows ***decrement and push*** methodology while pushing to stack.

`Opcode Fetch` in 8085 is typically 4 T states. However for `CALL` instruction, it takes 2 additional T states. It is because - After the fetch and decode, the stack pointer has to be decremented ahead of the first `Memory Write` cycle that will store the current PC's MSB to the stack.

During the first `Memory Write`, the value is pushed and the stack pointer is decremented again by the processor. This is done in parallel, so that next `Memory Write` cycle can begin immediately without losing additional T states. In the second `Memory Write`, PC's LSB is pushed to the stack, but the stack pointer need not be decremented as there are no further writes coming.

`Memory Read` cycle is where the branching address is stored in WZ internal registers.

Each `Memory Write` is 3 T states and each `Memory Read` is 3 T states as well.

So total [T states](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Timing-Diagram-and-machine-cycles-of-8085-Microprocessor_7812/) = 4 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 18

**RET INSTRUCTION IN 8085**

It consists of: `Opcode Fetch`, `Memory Read`, `Memory Read`

Again, `Opcode Fetch` is 4 T states. However 8085 follows ***pop and increment*** methodology while popping from stack. The stack pointer is already pointing to the LSB of the return address, so there is no need to increment the pointer beforehand.

During the first `Memory Read`, the pointed value is read, and the stack pointer is incremented by the processor as well in parallel. During the next `Memory Read`, the MSB of the return address is read and the stack pointer is again incremented in parallel.

So total [T states](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Timing-Diagram-and-machine-cycles-of-8085-Microprocessor_7812/) = 4 + 3 + 3  = 10

So in `RET`, there are no additional T states needed after `Opcode Fetch` unlike in `CALL`.

Comment: So my guess was right. But there's this naive question, Why does a decrement take 2 T-States?

Comment: stack pointer is just a register, only one clock cycle or T state is needed to decrement or increment it. The value of the register can be then passed to address bus on the next cycle. Extra cycle should be due to registering in between.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I really enjoyed the clarity! I've deleted my vague comment.